Trip documentation or travel documentation?
When a traveler purchases a package from a travel agency, the agent hands out a set of documents, typically including the flights, hotels, itinerary, contract, etc.
This is typically given after the last payment and as a confirmation of "all set to depart".
Do you call that set of documents "trip documentation" or "travel documentation"?

https://www.iata.org/en/publications/newsletters/iata-knowledge-hub/the-most-important-travel-documents-for-your-trip/ Travel documents. IATA knows best. :)

You purchase the package from a travel agency, not to.

@Lambie The documents listed there are personal information like passport, needed by regulatory agencies, not information about the trip.

I don't think there's a common term for what the OP describes. Any descriptive phrase will work.

@Barmar No, it includes travel itinerary stuff. In any case, the word he needs is documents and not documentation. Travel Itinerary Details
Flight ticket details, accommodation reservations, car rental confirmation, all are important for your trip. "Keeping up with all your reservations can be difficult and having copies of your itinerary and reservations with you can make your trip go much smoother"

And the term it uses for this is "Travel Itinerary Details".

@Barmar Yeah, but that includes documents. Can we stop please?

Woudn't you normally get details about hotel, flights, booking, itinerary, visa requirements, etc, when you initially book the holiday, or possibly even when you enquire about the holiday (particularly if it's a standard set of documents for a package trip or one-off tour), not when you make the final payment? Or do you mean something more like a receipt saying a holiday is paid in full after you buy it on credit?

Whatever the answer might be, this question has a certain old-timey flavour: I suspect few people younger than 50 have ever held in their hands what the OP describes.

@Barmar had a perfectly sensible comment which does not deserve to be treated dismissively with 'Can we stop please?' While itineraries and suchlike may occasionally be listed on the databases of required travel documents, they appear there only in so far as the immigration and other border control authorities require them for entry into the relevant country. The OP is, on the other hand, mostly concerned with the documents that have an entirely different purpose (which they would have in a trip that is entirely domestic, as well as in international ones).

So, considering it's not the ones defined in the IATA, like passport, and so on, but the ones created by the agent (no matter if handed in paper or as a web page in HTML) I'm not yet clear if an agent should say "We've sent you a WhatsApp with your travel documentation, that's all you need to enjoy!" or "We've sent you a WhatsApp with your trip documentation, that's all you need to enjoy!" - IATA includes also itinteraries in that listing... should the agent say then "We've sent you a WhatsApp with your travel documents, that's all you need to enjoy!"
If so, please write as an answer.

No, documentation here at all. That is a misuse of the word. Please go look it up in a good dictionary. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/documentation

You can't send docs via Whatsapp.

It is expected that those who pose questions give some evidence of their own research and of any remaining difficulty they have. You did not, so someone kindly merely marked the question down, rather than voting to close it, as may happen with more experienced questioners who omit any personal research, I have answered it on the basis that the question deals with subtleties of meaning that may not have been immediately obvious.

@XaviMontero, when I said that the question has 'a certain old-timey flavour' I meant not only that such documents are likely to be electronic rather than on paper, but also that booking a trip nowadays, for most people, results in numerous separate e-mail messages, each with a different invoice/receipt/confirmation/ticket/reminder/reconfirmation/etc., without anybody ever giving them one thing and telling them 'Here is everything you need'.

Can you say what difference you see between 'Trip…' and 'Travel documentation…'?

The answer to this depends on our understanding of trip as opposed to travel, and document as opposed to documentation. In practice the differences are small and unlikely to have much practical significance.
we may understand travel as

Cambridge
travel, noun: the activity of traveling, usually over a long distance

whereas trip is often regarded as a restricted sort of travel

Cambridge
trip, noun: a journey in which you go somewhere, usually for a short time, and come back again

Merriam Webster has trip as

Merriam Webster
a: voyage, journey
b: a single round or tour on a business errand

and travel as

Merriam Webster
a: the act of traveling : passage
b: a journey especially to a distant or unfamiliar place : tour, trip —often used in plural.
synonymous with trip

M-W's first definition of travel as the act of travelling therefore may encompass more than a mere trip
There is therefore a feeling that travel may be longer, more distant, more complex than a simple trip. The choice depends on circumstance.
As to document/documentation we have

Cambridge
documentation: pieces of paper containing official information

and

Merriam Webster
documentation: the provision of documents in substantiation

It follows that documentation is a unifying concept that covers a set of documents. Loosely, the two are synonymous because the set is little different from the total of its component parts.

These are just travel papers or travel documents. I would strongly argue that documentation is something distinct from documents.

@tchrist So would I.

@tchrist, there is a question on this site that directly addresses the concerns you and Lambie raise, How to distinguish between "document" and "documentation"?, but it has unfortunately been closed. It probably deserves a more complete answer than the ones posted there so far.

The answer is "yes."  Either will do.  I would probably use "documents" rather than "documentation," however, and "travel documents" typically denotes passports and visas and the like, so I would probably prefer "trip documents."  But in the context, "documents" may be fine by itself, and, in most cases, I would probably use "documents for your trip," as in please be certain to print the documents for your trip in case a network connection is unavailable.
In short, "trip" will denote the package sold by the travel agency with less ambiguity, because "travel" is a broader word with less specificity.

Your question "What do you call...?" suggests there's a standard name for these papers.  I don't think there is.  You could call it a travel packet or less likely a trip packet or a number of other things. Travel packet is used quite frequently. Governmental agencies often issue such packets to their employees who are about to travel, especially to foreign countries. But "packet" is a generic term and "travel packet" could also be used of something a shop might sell, with a comb or brush, scissors, toiletries, a small sewing kit, etc.
